# Log4j No appenders could be found for logger (org.apache.hadoop.util.shell)

Tags: java, maven, hadoop, logging, log4j

I am using maven for my project. When I run a program I am getting this error and because of this I cannot see my program execution progress though the program is producing expected outputs.

```
srimanth@srimanth-Inspiron-N5110:~/CCHD&CCHA/mangoes$ mvn exec:java -q -Dexec.mainClass=bananas.MapReduceColorCount -Dexec.args="hdfs://localhost:9000/users.avrofile hdfs://localhost:9000/pleaseatleastnow6"
log4j:WARN No appenders could be found for logger (org.apache.hadoop.util.Shell).
log4j:WARN Please initialize the log4j system properly.
log4j:WARN See http://logging.apache.org/log4j/1.2/faq.html#noconfig for more info.
srimanth@srimanth-Inspiron-N5110:~/CCHD&CCHA/mangoes$
```

Here is my pom.xml

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
  <groupId>fruits</groupId>
  <artifactId>mangoes</artifactId>
  <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
  <name>Hadoop</name>
  <description>Hadoop
Hadoop</description>
<dependencies>
<dependency>
  <groupId>org.apache.avro</groupId>
  <artifactId>avro</artifactId>
  <version>1.7.6</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
  <groupId>org.apache.avro</groupId>
  <artifactId>avro-mapred</artifactId>
  <version>1.7.6</version>
  <classifier>hadoop2</classifier>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.hadoop</groupId>
    <artifactId>hadoop-yarn-api</artifactId>
    <version>2.6.0</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.hadoop</groupId>
    <artifactId>hadoop-common</artifactId>
    <version>2.6.0</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.hadoop</groupId>
    <artifactId>hadoop-hdfs</artifactId>
    <version>2.6.0</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.hadoop</groupId>
    <artifactId>hadoop-mapreduce-client-app</artifactId>
    <version>2.6.0</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.hadoop</groupId>
    <artifactId>hadoop-mapreduce-client-common</artifactId>
    <version>2.6.0</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.hadoop</groupId>
    <artifactId>hadoop-yarn-client</artifactId>
    <version>2.6.0</version>
</dependency>

<dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.hadoop</groupId>
    <artifactId>hadoop-client</artifactId>
    <version>2.6.0</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.hadoop</groupId>
    <artifactId>hadoop-mapreduce-client-core</artifactId>
    <version>2.6.0</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.hadoop</groupId>
    <artifactId>hadoop-yarn-common</artifactId>
    <version>2.6.0</version>
</dependency>
</dependencies>

<build>
<pluginManagement>
    <plugins>
      <plugin>
        <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
        <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>3.3</version>
        <configuration>
          <source>1.7</source>
          <target>1.7</target>
        </configuration>
      </plugin>
      <plugin>
  <groupId>org.apache.avro</groupId>
  <artifactId>avro-maven-plugin</artifactId>
  <version>1.7.6</version>
  <executions>
    <execution>
      <phase>generate-sources</phase>
      <goals>
        <goal>schema</goal>
      </goals>
      <configuration>
        <sourceDirectory>${project.basedir}/../</sourceDirectory>
        <outputDirectory>${project.basedir}/target/generated-sources/</outputDirectory>
      </configuration>
    </execution>
  </executions>
</plugin>
    </plugins>
    </pluginManagement>
  </build>

</project>
```

am I missing any dependency? How/Where do I configure log4j properly. Thanks in advance. I would appreciate some help.

Comment: First it is not an error but only a warning; an important warning nonetheless.

Comment: Ok. But I want to see execution progress. How do I remove this warning ?

Comment: @SrimanthDuggineni, make sure that you have placed the log4j.properties file in classpath..

Answer (score 7, accepted):

For Maven you have to put the log4j.properties or log4j.xml file in main/resources folder. that's it. nothing else to do. Create your own property file. Something like this.

```
log4j.rootLogger=DEBUG, CA

log4j.appender.CA=org.apache.log4j.ConsoleAppender

log4j.appender.CA.layout=org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout
log4j.appender.CA.layout.ConversionPattern=%-4r [%t] %-5p %c %x - %m%n
```

You can give INFO, ERROR, WARNING, FATAL and DEBUG to the log4j.rootlogger property. replace debug with whichever mode of logs suits the best for your needs.

Comment: I gave DEBUG to the log4j.rootLogger property, placed the file in main/resources and then complied the project. Now I can all DEBUG messages :) It worked like charm

Answer (score 0):

Follow the URL given in the warning. It will given some guiding information.

```
http://logging.apache.org/log4j/1.2/faq.html#noconfig
```

From the site:

> This occurs when the default configuration files log4j.properties and
>   log4j.xml can not be found and the application performs no explicit
>   configuration. log4j uses Thread.getContextClassLoader().getResource()
>   to locate the default configuration files and does not directly check
>   the file system. Knowing the appropriate location to place
>   log4j.properties or log4j.xml requires understanding the search
>   strategy of the class loader in use. log4j does not provide a default
>   configuration since output to the console or to the file system may be
>   prohibited in some environments.

You need either a `log4j.properties` or `log4j.xml`. Construct either that suits your need best. Read the [Log4J manua](http://logging.apache.org/log4j/1.2/manual.html)l will give you some knowledge to help construct the config file